# SelectList in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Selected Value not working in SelectList

entity "Material"

```
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Unit { get; set; }
    public double? Count { get; set; }
    public double? Amount { get; set; }
    public double? Cost { get; set; }
}
```

[image: data from db]

part of code for controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Material{
    ...

    ViewData["Material"] = new SelectList(await Materials(), "Id", "Name",
                 sqlParameters[0].Value);
}
```

part of code for view

```
<select asp-for="Material" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Material"></select>
```

I tried to pass the selected value in 3 ways

1. ViewData["Material"] = new SelectList(await Materials(), "Id", "Name",
   21);
2. ViewData["Material"] = new SelectList(await Materials(), "Id", "Name",
   "21");
3. ViewData["Material"] = new SelectList(await Materials(), "Id", "Name",
   "Whey");

But I don't have any errors. In select list I see first item instead of second. List of items shows everything is fine and I have no problems here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `Materials`, what type is it, what data is present there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Selected Value not working in SelectList. But I don't have any errors. In select list I see first item instead
> of second. List of items shows everything is fine and I have no
> problems here.

Actually, my first point at your `<select asp-for="Material">` its a type of [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which expecting list of items, I am not quite sure if you have shared the correct model because here we need something type of selectList of List Of Object but your shared material is a single class.

In addition, for keeping the dropdown item selected within [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-6.0) we have overload items [selected value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist.selectedvalue?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-rendering-selectlist-selectedvalue) as following:

[image]

In your scenario its  Id more specifically, 21 (Whey) which you are trying to keep selected. But string wouldn't be the correct parameter which is a key but we need value.

**How I reproduce your Issue:**

Model:

```
 public class MaterialClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }

    }
```

**Note:** Just considering your Id and Name fields.

View Model:

```
public class MaterialViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> MaterialClassList { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** As we need list of items so I made a view model of SelectListItem within `<select asp-for="ListTypeObject">` thus, taking this view model. However, its not mandatory, you still can use Material class.

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Material()
        {


            ViewData["Material"] = new SelectList(await Materials(), "Id", "Name", 21);
            return View();
                         
        }
```

Materials() Method:

As you haven't shared details of Materials method, therefore, assuming it returns a list of your MaterialClass objects. Hence, I have replicated as following:

```
public async Task<List<MaterialClass>> Materials()
        {
            var materials = new List<MaterialClass>()
                 {
                  new MaterialClass {Name = "Milk", Id = 20},
                  new MaterialClass {Name = "Whey", Id= 21},
                  new MaterialClass {Name = "Jgv", Id = 22},
                 };
            return materials;
        }
```

View:

```
@model MyProject.ModelFolder.MaterialViewModel

<select asp-for="MaterialClassList" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Material"></select>
```

Debug:

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you noticed the output, I am getting the expected result. Just make sure about your `sqlParameters[0].Value` and try to debug and check if your selected value object has the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it works for me. You might want to try it without the database:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
       var materials = new List<Material>
       {
            new Material
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Id = 1
            },
            new Material
            {
                Name = "Test2",
                Id = 2
            }
        };
        ViewData["Material"] = new SelectList(materials, "Id", "Name", 2);
        return Page();
}
```

And in the .cshtml file:

```
<select asp-items="ViewBag.Material"></select>
```

And are you sure your code is being called? The function name `Material` doesn't appear to be called by the framework. If you want your code to execute on an HTTP GET request, you would need to rename the method to `OnGetAsync`